# Where can I find a list of operators that are called when a certain operator is not found in a class?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

For example if we have the method **lt**() implemented in a class and we try to use the greater than operator it will not raise an exception because it will use the less than method to compute a result. Is there some kind of table that exists that shows all of the operators and the operators that are called if the original operators were not defined? I did some searching but did not find what I was looking for.

Thank you

EDIT: Trying to find a list of magic methods that are called when an operator is used with objects but no operator method is defined in the object's class

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you trying to find a list of all magic methods that are called when operators are used?

Comment: Yes Precisely, Trying to find the list of magic methods that are called when each operator fails

Answer (score 0):

If want to overload an operator, you can implement the *special* (dunder `__`) methods. You will find them here - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names
If you are looking for operators for efficient iteration purposes check the `operator` module.

Comment: You may want to specify that dunder is short for double underscore `__`